# How can I access the version number of any other target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an App that installs an executable (XPCService) that it sends commands to for privileged actions. This executable is an other target in my project. To avoid re-installing it every time I send a command, I need to check its version and cross check that with what my app can install.

So I know how to access the version number of the class's target with the following:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]`

This is useful because the installed executable can respond to a command that I have called `-getVersionWithReply:` with its version.

So how do I, within either a class that is built in my main app's target or a class that is shared between both targets, get the version of the not yet installed executable? Could I use the Product Name?

Comment: I do not understand the Q. "the version of the not yet installed executable?" If it is not installed, it has no version!?

Comment: I'm basically referencing the version of the target in the bundle, it's not yet installed by SMJobBless

Comment: IIRC the XPC service is a bundle, too. (Where long ago that I worked with XPC services.) So why don't you get it with `+bundleWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: unfortunately the XPCService in question is not a bundle, though in some cases it can be

Comment: Looking to `NSFileManager`'s file attributes I do not see any version attribute key. If there would be one, storing the version in the bundle's plist would be redundant. The finder doesn't show such an information on the executable, too. It looks like there is no version information on file system layer. Can you put the version information in the file name (very old school).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find what I think is the right solution to this problem:

Essentially since the XPC Service was installed with SMJobBless, I could do the following:

```
- (NSString *)_installedVersion
{
    NSString *installedVersion = nil;
    NSDictionary *installedPrivilegedAgentJobData;

    installedPrivilegedAgentJobData = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)SMJobCopyDictionary(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.privilegedAgentMachServiceName);

    if (installedPrivilegedAgentJobData != nil) {
        NSString *installedPath = [[installedPrivilegedAgentJobData objectForKey:@"ProgramArguments"] objectAtIndex:0];


        NSURL *installedPathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:installedPath];

        NSDictionary *installedInfoPlist = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL((CFURLRef)installedPathURL));
        if (installedInfoPlist != nil) {
            installedVersion = [installedInfoPlist objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
        }
    }
    return installedVersion;
}
```

I think this has to do with the fact that the XPCService's plist is inside the binary.

You can then compare this with the version of the XPCService that is not installed with something like:

```
- (NSString *)_currentVersion
{
    NSString *currentPath = self.privilegedAgentPathInBundle;
    NSURL *currentPrivilegedAgentURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:currentPath];
    NSDictionary *currentInfoPlist = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL((CFURLRef)currentPrivilegedAgentURL));
    return [currentInfoPlist objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *appVersion    = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] 
objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```